# Iphone--(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

Tags: iphone

I By using this command 
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

I can rotate my view automatically ,Is there any way to rotate and ellabarate and fit with screen.

Thanks in advance,
(Deepan)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the autoresizing properties of your views to make them resize to fit the screen.

For example, if you want a view to resize horizontally and vertically, you can use:

```
myView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

To control whether a view will automatically resize its subviews, you use the boolean `autoresizesSubviews` property.

To control how a container view will layout its subviews when the container view's size changes, you use the `contentMode` property.

For more information, refer to Apple's [UIView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).